# Why does WordPress 4.2.2 require FTP to update?

Tags: updates, upgrade, automatic-updates

I am trying to update to WordPress 4.2.2, but it requires FTP details.

Considering that everything WordPress-related is assigned to `apache`, and the server runs as `apache`, shouldn’t WordPress be able to upgrade without FTP?

WordPress is in the root. Here are the file owner/permissions:

```
/var/www (root):
    permissions: 750
    user: www
    group: apache

All WP folders:
    permissions: 755
    user: apache
    group: apache

All WP files:
    permissions: 644
    user: apache
    group: apache
```

The problem with FTP is that only the `www` user has FTP access, but it can’t work on directories assigned to `apache:apache`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue. Are you sure WordPress isn't running with the `www` user? I would try to make sure all your files have `77*` or `66*` access, instead of `74*` and `65*`. Also, make sure that you are running WordPress under the correct user. Now days, unless changed by web host, it is usually run under `www` by default.

---

After you are done updating/upgrading, be sure to return your permissions to normal. ;)